# how to check mean stack plugin compatibility with existing mean project

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

Hi currently I am working as front-end developer in some company using technology angular, bootstrap etc

eg:--recently I have to add new functionality tags input to the existing project.  I saw various demo over the internet for tags input but when I try to implement it is not functional some time compatibility issue some time other issues.most of my time get wasted in hit and trial method of implementing things what is the best way to check if exiting libraries will work smoothly wihout much hassle.

Comment: This question doesn't provide any information that would allow to give feedback. "compatibility issue" could be everything. If yoz get an error message, post it.

Comment: my  question was  how to check if new  plugin will be compatible with installed angular js and installed bootstrap css mainly.

Comment: What plugin? A browser Plugin, a bootstrap plugin, a jQuery plugin, ...? Without concrete information there is no way to answer this question.

Comment: eg: tags input  bootstrap plugin for my current case

Comment: There is no way to find out if a bootstrap plugin is compatible with Angular. Either the plugin docs mention it explicitly or you have to test it yourself.

Comment: really ???? anyway thanks. My whole point was time saving.